# I need the correct key combination for the end of file

Tags: java

```
While(input.Next()){

             record.Account(input.nextInt);
      }
```

I want the program to terminate when i type `ctr z` because i use windows on a dell computer but it will not terminate.

What is the correct key combination for the end of file in dell computer.

Comment: `input.nextInt()` is a **method** (not property).

Comment: The code you posted would not compile, assuming that `input` is an instance of `Scanner`.